# My first database connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I've bought a domain-hosting from a local company. Their customer service is pretty horrible.

My code for connecting to the database seems ok but still its not working. Here my code:

```
function __construct(){
    if(!@mysql_ping()){
        $this->db_connect();
    }
    $sql  = "SELECT value FROM settings WHERE field =  'auto_logout'";
    $res  = mysql_fetch_array($this->execute_single_query($sql));
    $this->LOGIN_DURATION = $res['value'];
}


private function db_connect(){
    // Mysql connect
    $link = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'created_who_has_all_prev', 'pass_note_my_cpanel_and_mysql_has_same_pass');

    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //echo 'Connected successfully<br/>';
    // Mysql select db select --->
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($this->DB, $link);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die ('Can\'t use specified Database : ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //echo "<br/>Database Selected<br/>";
    return $link;
}
```

And this is the snapshot:
[image]

Comment: Whose hosting this? I highly doubt that your user is 'root' since that is the initial account that is created with MySQL. So that user should be reserved for the admins at your hosting company. You should probably login with whatever username you blacked out in the screenshot

Comment: @immulatin my local hosting company gave me the root account to our shared hosting plan. Also to the OP, look up the documentation for MySQL functions. They are officially depreciated, and horrible. Consider re-writing to use MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that the link that you create isn't accessible. So, PHP tries to connect with defaults (apparently in your setup it means the user is `root`) and since it has no password, the connection fails which is the cause of most of your warning messages.

The last warning is a consequence of the others.

To fix this problem - as you haven't provided details of the actual parts that are executing the query - here is how to re-write your code so it works:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "(".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
}

$sql = "SELECT `value` FROM `settings` WHERE `field` = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s","auto_logout");

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "(".$stmt->errno.") ".$stmt->error;
}

$res = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
LOGIN_DURATION = $row['field'];
```

Comment: I didn't use u'r code but I used u'r opinion which u mentioned in the first paragraph in u'r answer. Thanks for helping. I'll try to use mysqli from next :)

Answer (score 1):

This is really sloppy code. I would use PDO as it is secure. Below is a class you can use but study how it works and why it works.

```
class Core {

    public $dbh; // handle of the db connection
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()  {

        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dealership", "root", "",$options);            

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$instance) {

        self::$instance = new self();

    }
    return self::$instance;
    }

    private function __clone() {}
    private function __wakeup() {}

}
```

In your code call it like below:

```
require "/classes/pdo.class.php";

 $db = Core::getInstance();

 $stmt = "SELECT `lastname` FROM `employees` where id = 2";

 $pep = $db->dbh->prepare($stmt);
 $pep->execute();


 foreach($pep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

     echo $row['lastname']. "\n";
  }
```

Make sure you look into PDO, prepared statments, and singleton pattern to understand why it works.

Comment: Nothing is perfectly secure. Please don't mislead new users. PDO is more secure though.

Comment: @Jhawinsss I never said perfectly secure, you did. I simply said it is secure. Depending on the level between other connections is a different topic. In addition, I wanted him to do the research and understand it but I guess he was just looking for the answer.

Comment: @Claudee You said "I simply said it is secure," therefore you said it is secure. The definition of secure is "free from or not exposed to danger or harm; safe." Saying something is "secure" implies that it is "perfectly secure," because that is what the word secure means.